# php - mysqli prepare giving me errors qhen start login

Tags: php

I create this code to check user login based in a form.
But is giving me erros..Is not finding nothing... just say "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!"

```
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_POST['email']));
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_POST['password']));

if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {

    header("Location: ../member?fail=1");
    exit();

} else {

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM public_users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $uid, $pwd);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($uid, $pwd);
    $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

        if($stmt->fetch()) {

           $secure_hash = password_verify($pwd, $stmt['password']);

           if($secure_hash == false) { 

              echo "Combination!";

           } else {

              echo "PASSWORD Combination!";
           }

        }

    } else {
        echo "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!";
    }        

}    

$stmt->close();
```

Please help this is for an text tomorrow at school :(

Comment: Time to open a manual: `$stmt->fetch()` fetches data into vars defined in `bind_result`.

Comment: hum ... ok... how can i do it?...

Comment: You shouldn't need to use both real_escape_string and prepared statements, just prepared statements should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to get an email and a password from your database, but the `password` field already hashed.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM public_users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
```

You should get a record only by email:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, password, age FROM public_users WHERE email = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $uid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($uid, $hashed_password, $age);
$stmt->store_result();
//.....
```

and next verify password:

```
$secure_hash = password_verify($pwd, $hashed_password);
```

Comment: You may want to include in your answer how the OP will fix `$secure_hash = password_verify($pwd, $stmt['password']);` as `$stmt['password']` is undefined and `$pwd` is overwritten by `bind_result`

Comment: how can i fix it... I'm learning prepared statments, so im sorry to be so boring.. eheheh i try it this..           $row = $stmt->fetch();      |                  $secure_hash = password_verify($pwd, $row['password']);

Comment: ok... i get it... is working... but explain to me why not use  $row['password'] instead var $hashed_password ?

Comment: one more question, if i want to use example another records "name or age" how can i get it from the fetch? example $row['age']?

Comment: Change your query to add another column name... `SELECT email, password,name` then add another variable to `bind_result` so it reads `$stmt->bind_result($uid, $hashed_password,$name);`. Now when you `fetch()` $name will be populated

Comment: but he he recognizes the record NAME as $name?, cus if i have a lot of records ... i just need to put them in a row right...

Comment: @user21312321 PHP don't recognize, it put values in variables just by order you call them